# Ember: "Map" mismatching api objects (asp.net web api) to ember models

Tags: ember.js, asp.net-web-api, ember-data

From what I’ve learned so far I know I have to do something in the serializer to solve the following, but a bit lost…

My api, return an object named PortfolioSummaryDto, and my Ember model is named “portfoliolistitem”.

This gives me the following error (which make sense)
*Encountered "portfolio_summary_dtos" in payload, but no model was found for model name "portfolio-summary-dto" (resolved model name using dealview1@serializer:-rest:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("portfolio_summary_dtos"))*

Going forward I’d like to call any API call, where the returned object/s and its names (and property names) are totally different from my Ember models.

Can someone point me to some reading how one “map” api objects to ember models?

Answer (score 0):

The general idea of ember.js is convention over configuration, thus you have to name your ember.js model's attributes and names in a specific way to access the underlying JSON properties of your payload.

PortfolioSummaryDto -> portfolio-summary-dto

However, if you want to customize this behavior you have override this convention.

To override the serializing process you have to implement your own ember.js serializer. Let's assume you don't want to implement an individual serializer for every ember.js model, then you could do the following for model names:

You create a configuration file like this in `app/application/model-mapping.js`:

```
export default {
  'PortfolioSummaryDto': 'portfoliolistitem',
  /* add more here */
}
```

That file represents the mapping from your model files to ember.js model files. Then you create or customize your application serializer this way:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import mappingTable from './model-mapping';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  modelNameFromPayloadKey(payloadKey) {
    return mappingTable[payloadKey] || payloadKey;
  }
});
```

Comment: that makes perfect sense, thanks!   how about mapping properties (guess I'm thinking "automapper" too much still, coming from .net/mvc)

Comment: see [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalize) for information about normalizing (changing) the JSON response you get from your server